# Mailchimp Magento Error

Tags: magento, mailchimp, php-ini

when a user subscribe newsletter it returns http 500 error
the error in blockquote is from server error_log and the condition below is from mailchimp which is throwing the following error

```
if (floor($info['http_code'] / 100) >= 4) {
            $errors = (isset($result['errors'])) ? $result['errors'] : '';
            throw new Mailchimp_Error($url, $result['title'], $result['detail'], $errors);
        }
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/jsbfurniture/public_html/lib/Ebizmarts/Mailchimp.php on line 273

Comment: Try increasing PHP's memory_limit. 33MB is not enough for Magento.

Comment: i also tried to set this 512mb same error nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all Customer Fields Mapping from Adminhtml.